# How to make vertically re-sizable div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm trying to make best possible solution for vertically re-sizable `div`.

This is how far I got, but I'm not sure if this is best practice.

### EDIT

I want to make this code reusable, as you can see in my case it's quite difficulta if I have more then 2,3 different re-sizers.

---

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEefz/)

### JS

```
var moveHandler = function (e) {
    var leftPos = e.pageX - $("#container").position().left;
    var rightPos = $("#container").width() - e.pageX + 40;
    $("#separator").css("left", leftPos + "px");
    $("#left-side").css("right", rightPos + "px");
    $("#right-side").css("left", leftPos + "px");
}

$("#separator").on('mousedown', function () {
    $("#container").on('mousemove.resize', moveHandler);
    $("#separator").css("background-color", "gray");
});
$(window).on('mouseup', function () {
    $("#separator").css("background-color", "");
    $("#container").off('mousemove.resize')
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-side">.</div>
    <div id="separator"></div>
    <div id="right-side">.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Get rid of the fixed height and let them resize themselves.

Comment: @Rob I don't want them to re-size themselves, I want to manually re-size them. Question is, how can I improve the code.

Comment: Down voter care to explain why down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is pure JavaScript which handles any number of appropriately configured slider elements:

```
(function () {
  function mouseDown (ev) {
    function mouseMove (ev) {
      originX = parseInt (window.getComputedStyle (slider).left, 10) + 
                  ev.screenX - originX;
      if (originX >= 5 && originX <= cWidth - 10)
        slider.style.left = slider.previousElementSibling.style.width = 
            slider.nextElementSibling.style.left = originX + 'px';  
      originX = ev.screenX;
    }

    function mouseUp (ev) {
      document.removeEventListener ('mousemove', mouseMove, false)
      document.removeEventListener ('mouseup', mouseUp, false)
      slider.classList.remove ('active');
    }

    var slider = this,
        originX = ev.screenX,
        cWidth = parseInt (window.getComputedStyle (slider.parentNode).width, 10);
    slider.classList.add ('active');
    document.addEventListener ('mousemove', mouseMove, false)
    document.addEventListener ('mouseup', mouseUp, false)
  }

  [].forEach.call (document.querySelectorAll ('.slider'), function (slider) {
      var left = slider.previousElementSibling,
          right = slider.nextElementSibling;

      slider.parentNode.classList.add ('container');

      slider.classList.remove ('active');
      slider.addEventListener ('mousedown', mouseDown, false);

      left.style.position = right.style.position = 'absolute';
      left.style.width = right.style.left = window.getComputedStyle (slider).left;
      left.style.left = right.style.right = '0px';
    });
}) ();
```

The configuration is as follows:

```
 <div>  <!- container -->
    <div></div>  <!- left side -->
    <div class="slider"></div>  <!- slider -->
    <div></div>  <!- right side -->
 </div>
```

requires the following css:

```
.container { position: relative; }

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 5px;
    cursor: col-resize;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;    
}
```

The code is triggered by finding a classname `slider` and it then fixes up most of the style values.

See the fiddle for more details : http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/VCdE5/

Comment: While this is decent code, it has some minor issues, like it's still tracking mousemovement when outside of screen and coming back mouse position with resize line isn't in synch. I'll give you upvote, but for accepted answer I need it working properly.